# Wrong result on VIM multiple lines write (end of line)

Tags: vim

I have the following file content opened in VIM:

```
123 
234 
345 
546 
567 
678 
789 
~
~
~
~
~
```

I want to add `;` to end of the each line. For that I go to the end of the first line and use a vertical selection pressing `CTRL + v`.

I select the first **7 lines** (the lines with numbers) and then I press `SHIFT + I` and move the cursor to the end of the line. I write `;` and then I press `Esc`.

The result is this:

```
123;
2334
3435
5436
5637
6738
7839
```

...while I expected:

```
123;
233;
343;
543;
563;
673;
783;
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Note that this is just an example how to reproduce the issue. I know that I can use a regexp  or a macro to do the same thing, but I want to find the answer to the questions above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
:1,7 s/$/;/
```

**Edit**: Change <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> into <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> can achieve your purpose.

Comment: I know that, but I want to find why this is happening... See the edit.

Comment: @IngoKarkat That's great. Discovered another feature of VIM. :-)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> is for *prepending* at the beginning of the visual blockwise selection; by moving the cursor to the end, you've ruined it! (Vim doesn't seem to recognize that you've moved the cursor, and thinks the `3` on which you've started the edit is what you've entered. It's debatable whether this is a bug.)

What you need to use is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, which *appends* at the end of all selected lines.

Comment: *..you've ruined it* -- but in what way? Why is `3` prepended instead of `;`?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: I think this is an unintended consequence of the current implemenation; might call it a bug.

Comment: I would say, this looks like a bug

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Will you work on it (thanks for all your fixes!), or should I report this to vim_dev?!

Comment: I am looking into this, but haven't found a good solution yet, so I think, it doesn't hurt to report it to vim_dev

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks so much for all your work improving on Vim; if only there were more of you :-) I'll keep this issue on my list, so that it won't be forgotten. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You've only told vim to replace the first occurrence. Instead, go to the end of line 1 and press `ctrl-v` and select to the bottom of the file. Then press `:` to move to the command line. This will now show `:'<,'>`. If you type `s/$/;/g` here and hit return, you will get a semi-colon at the end of every selected line.

Hope this helps.